# Get string after nth instance of a character and before an instance of another character

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have a table (documentfiles) full of network paths. I need to extract the document name from column 'destination' minus the file extension, and then insert this into a column in the same table.

For example, a sample path I would have is:

J:\RootFolder\Subfolder\Reference\481789.pdf

I need to extract 481789 and insert this into the next column along called 'column3'.
The structure is the same on each path, so I'm looking for the string after the 4th instance of `'\'`
and before the `'.'`

I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to tackle this, but I have tried the below so far and I have managed to trim off the extension and only the first instance of `'\'`. I am struggling with nesting CHARINDEX to get the 4th instance along.

I've also not got far enough along to then carry out the insert yet.

```
SELECT
  destination,
  SUBSTRING(destination, CHARINDEX('\', destination),
  CHARINDEX('.', destination) - CHARINDEX('\', destination)) AS substring
FROM documentfiles
```

Comment: Use Python. Setting it up will take a while but once you have the connection configured then writing the code will be much easier.

Comment: which database system are you using and regular expression could help immensly

Comment: TAG your RDBMS; and don't store an extra column, use a computed column.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server you can do

```
DECLARE @t varchar(100) = 'J:\RootFolder\Subfolder\Reference\481789.pdf';
SELECT
LEFT(reverse(left(reverse(@t), charindex('\', reverse(@t)) -1)),
  charindex('.',reverse(left(reverse(@t), charindex('\', reverse(@t)) -1))) - 1)
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 481789 |

```
DECLARE @t varchar(100) = 'J:\RootFolder\Subfolder\Reference\481789.pdf';
WITH ext AS (
  SELECT reverse(left(reverse(@t), charindex('\', reverse(@t)) -1)) as a)
SELECT LEFT(a,charindex('.',a)-1) FROM ext
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 481789 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q-EFirzK)

Comment: How would I change this so it points to the table I need the information from? I have around 3.8 million rows I need to do this for, rather than just the one string.

Comment: every where you see a @t replace it with the column and add a FROM mytable